# Gawk/Grep - remove lifes if doesn't contain 3 column

Tags: unix, awk, grep, cygwin, gawk

Okay so i have for example,

```
Email:Phone:Name
Email2:Phone2:Name2
```

( 3 columns )

However some lines only contain 2 columns example,

```
Email3:Phone3
```

Notice #3 contains no name/3rd column

Question is how do I remove lines containing only 2 columns.

Answer (score 5):

Filter by the number of fields, `NF`, using `:` as the field separator:

```
awk -F: 'NF == 3' file
```

That is, `NF == 3` is a filter, matching lines that have 3 fields (`NF` contains the number of fields in the current line). For lines that match this filter, the default command `print` is executed,
resulting in your desired output.

Comment: Just for golfing, maybe this can work also `awk -F: '$3' file`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou no, that would fail if $3 was present but null or a value that evaluates numerically to zero.

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/^[^:]*:[^:]*$/d' file
```

`d` - delete lines containing only 2 fields separated by `:`